# Macos Hadoop 3.1.1 - Failed to start namenode. java.io.IOException: Could not parse line: "Filesystem 1024-blocks Used Available Capacity Mounted on"

Tags: macos, hadoop, homebrew

I install hadoop 3.1.1 by homebrew on mac os.

core-site.xml config as following:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>file:///Users/yishuihanxiao/Personal_Home/ws/DB_Data/hadoop/hdfs/tmp</value>
        <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
    </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml as following:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
  <property>  
      <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>  
      <value>file:///Users/yishuihanxiao/Personal_Home/ws/DB_Data/hadoop/hdfs/names</value>  
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.checkpoint.dir</name>
    <value>file:///Users/yishuihanxiao/Personal_Home/ws/DB_Data/hadoop/hdfs/checkpoint</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.checkpoint.edits.dir</name>
    <value>file:///Users/yishuihanxiao/Personal_Home/ws/DB_Data/hadoop/hdfs/checkpoint</value>
  </property>
  <property>  
      <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>  
      <value>file:///Users/yishuihanxiao/Personal_Home/ws/DB_Data/hadoop/hdfs/data</value>  
  </property>
</configuration>
```

when I startdfs, the name node cannot start. from the log, I can see following exception:

```
2018-09-26 09:49:47,576 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system shutdown complete.
2018-09-26 09:49:47,583 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.io.IOException: Could not parse line: Filesystem   1024-blocks     Used Available Capacity  Mounted on
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.DF.parseOutput(DF.java:195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.DF.getFilesystem(DF.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeResourceChecker$CheckedVolume.<init>(NameNodeResourceChecker.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeResourceChecker.addDirToCheck(NameNodeResourceChecker.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeResourceChecker.<init>(NameNodeResourceChecker.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startCommonServices(FSNamesystem.java:1155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.startCommonServices(NameNode.java:788)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:714)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:937)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:910)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1643)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1710)
```

I search a log and cannot find any usefull info.

Comment: Doesn't matter, but `fs.default.name` shouldn't be in HDFS site

Comment: but the namenode cannot stat, so the hadoop cannot work.

Comment: I understand that, but if your configuration files are misconfigured with the wrong files, then it **also** won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Running 3.1.1 also from Homebrew... (I'm also using Java 10, but I would suggest setting `JAVA_HOME` in `hadoop-env.sh` to be Java 8 otherwise)

If I

1. From the question, replace `/Users/yishuihanxiao/Personal_Home/ws/DB_Data` with `/tmp` so that my files are under `/tmp/hadoop/hdfs`
2. Again, from the question, remove `fs.default.name` from `hdfs-site.xml` because it shouldn't be a property there
3. Individually run `hdfs namenode -format`, then start with `hdfs namenode`, then the namenode starts. I can access the NameNode UI, but there are no datanodes.
4. Open separate terminal window for running `hdfs datanode`.

Then that starts okay and joins the namenode process without error (shown in logs and UI), and I can go to the Web UI's for both namenode and datanode, and do other Hadoop tasks such as startup YARN

Comment: I also can run hdfs namenode and hdfs datanode, but cannot start by run sbin/start-dfs.sh

Comment: Personally, I get `connection failed` because I'm not running an SSH server

Comment: I find, it start hdfs namenode with --workers, it will failed with such issue.

Comment: @cricket_007 how to start yarn? meet the same problem when running start-yarn.sh