# Hadoop 3.1.1 Mac OS Namenode Issues

Tags: macos, hadoop, namenode

I had a Hadoop on my machine running but I was running into some compiler issues, so I deleted it and started fresh.

I was following this setup: https://www.guru99.com/how-to-install-hadoop.html

When I run `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs namenode -format`
Terminal doesn't return any thing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: That link has a few steps not necessary as of Hadoop 2.x, and definitely not Hadoop3, but why are you expecting the format command to have any output? The shown image seems to show `start-dfs` output, not the format output

Comment: I'm getting no outputs for my Hadoop specific commands. Even hadoop version gives me no output. I should be receiving some confirmation or starting and shutdown message.

Comment: There might be a `log4j.properties` file missing in your Hadoop download folder

Comment: i have the file in `usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/hadoop/` i downloaded using homebrew

Comment: Hmm. I tried namenode format a few weeks ago from Homebrew on 3.1.1 and it worked fine for me. I can't remember if there was output or not, but starting the services, it did log to the console

Comment: It was on this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/52531871/2308683

Comment: my console only shows that I opened terminal. But no service staring. How did you do you download and setup?

Comment: `brew install hadoop`. I don't remember changing anything other than some XML files and the `hadoop-env.sh` file for Java settings

Answer (score 1):

run with sudo will get you result
for example

```
sudo hdfs namenode -format
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fix it by following

Change to etc file for adjusting the files hadoop-env , core-site, mapred, yarn

Change to sbin to do format and lunch hds services

Comment: can you be specific on how to change?

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure that you already adjust the files hadoop-env , core-site, mapred, yarn then processed to namenode format