# Receive Operation Not Permitted Error when starting HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

This is my first time setting up the Hadoop pseudo-distributed mode. I was able to follow my course instruction to install with no issue until the very last step to start up the nodes with this command: sbin/start-dfs.sh. I received an operation not permitted error.

My terminal does have full disk access. And I enabled localhost access on my Mac with this command sudo apachectl. But neither addresses the issue. If successful I should get a response like image 2. But I got this site can't be reach response when connecting to localhost.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you removed executable permission on `bin/hdfs`? Or is it missing?  Try to run `hadoop namenode` and `hadoop datanode` in separate terminals and see if both start sucessfully

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am not sure how to check whether executable permission is removed. Is it supposed to be removed or not? I included the content of the file in this post. I am also not sure how to run the node seperately. The command I found online did not work. (./hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode)

Comment: We don't need the file. It should be present if you want to run executable binaries.. Run `ls -l $HADOOP_HOME/bin`, You should see at least `rwxrw--- ... hdfs`

Comment: These are the steps I took several years ago on my Mac to get it running. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52531871/2308683

Comment: @OneCricketeer I was able to start the processes by following your step. But now as I tried to stop them, running the sbin/stop-dfs.sh gave me the same operation not permitted error. And trying hdfs namenode stop returned me this message "namenode is running as process 4384.  Stop it first and ensure /tmp/hadoop-duyanzhen-namenode.pid file is empty before retry." Can you please help me with how to stop them?

Comment: I'm not sure. I guess you can use `kill` command directly using the process id (then remove the pid file manually), as instructed, but I thought both commands just ran directly in the terminal, so Ctrl+C would stop them

Answer (score 0):

Try to tick the sshd-keygen-wrapper in the Setting -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Full Disk Access. I solved by above.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> Try to tick the sshd-keygen-wrapper in the Setting -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Full Disk Access. I solved by above.
> The actions above is ok for me